# Proving that this homomorphism is onto

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am self studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford and I have this question on which I am struck. I know it's not hard but still I couldn't think about it.

> On page $171$ author writes : Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ an $R$-module, then prove that the map $R \to Ra$ given by $r \to ra$ is an $R$-module epimorphism.

I proved it be homomorphism but I am struggling to prove it onto, i.e., to show for each $ra$ there exists an $r$ such that $r \to ra$.

Can anyone please tell what would be that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the question. After finding the actual theorem, Hungerford says to let $a\in A$, then define the map $R\to Ra$, $r\mapsto ra$. To show this is a surjection, let $ra\in Ra$. Then obviously $r$ itself is an element of $R$ that maps onto $ra$. There isn't really anything to show here.

Comment: The "key" here is that by definition, elements of $Ra$ look like $ra$ for some $r\in R$. Just take that $r$ as the thing mapping onto $ra$.